# can any body tell me the difference, why they produce different results?

Tags: olap, mdx, cube

1)

```
select non empty 

           [Measures].[carded transactions] on 0,
           {[Date Dimension].[DATE].&[39446]:[Date Dimension].[DATE].&[39505]} on 1

from [Food and Beverage]

where 
(
       FILTER(
      {( [Revenue Center].[Revenue Center].[Revenue Center]
       * [Date Dimension].[Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Day] 
       * [Date Dimension].[Day Name].[Day Name])}
       , [Measures].[FnB Checks] > 0
             )
 )
```

2)

```
select non empty 

    [Measures].[carded transactions] on 0,
    {[Date Dimension].[DATE].[DATE]} on 1

FROM

 (SELECT 
        ([Date Dimension].[Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Day].&[2008]&[1]&[1] 
        : [Date Dimension].[Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Day].&[2008][2]&[60]) ON  0  
  FROM [Food and Beverage]
 ) 

where 
(  
  FILTER(
           {( [Revenue Center].[Revenue Center].[Revenue Center]
       * [Date Dimension].[Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Day] 
       * [Date Dimension].[Day Name].[Day Name])}
    , [Measures].[FnB Checks] > 0
        )
  )
```

thanx. help appreciated.

Comment: this is the best i could do, Ilya...and  I m sorry, I might have done it by mistake...

Comment: does anybody has any idea about the question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are across different date periods that is why...